# renaming internal file name in zip file

Tags: java, linux, zip, nio

this is a follow up question to this discussion

[renaming file name inside a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126450/renaming-file-name-inside-a-zip-file)

i used the suggestion given in the above post to rename the internal file name of a zip file. It works great in windows. When i take to Linux, as mentioned in the last comment, the rename happens only if the file is owned by the id running the java code. If i run the code as a "xxx" id and the file is owned by "yyy" the rename is not happening. This even if the file permission is 777. I tried to check if the sourcefile writable and it is. No idea why this would be the case. Please share your thoughts. thanks as always.

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file://"+ SourceDirName + "/" + 
SourceFileName);
FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri,       
Collections.<String,Object>emptyMap())) { 
Path sourceURI = zipfs.getPath("/"+ intFileName); 
Path destinationURI = zipfs.getPath("/"+ ZipInternalName); 
Files.move(sourceURI, destinationURI);
```

intFileName is the zip internal file name
ZipInternalName is the new name i want to use to rename the intFileName

To check if the id that is running the code has write access to the SourceURI, i tried this

```
if (Files.isWritable(sourceURI)){
System.out.println("true");
}
```

and i got a true for writable but again rename doesnt work

Also tried

```
Files.move(sourceURI, sourceURI.resolvesibling(destinationURI);
```

but no use

Comment: the linux zip may be trying to create a NEW zip file and copying over everything with the changes applied to that copy. just because you have rights to the original .zip doesn't mean you have the rights to create new files in the containing directory, then delete the original and rename the new one. setting the containing dir to 777 would confirm this.

Comment: Would you care providing some sample code and an example setup?

Comment: @md1980 Not in a comment. Comments are not appropriate for code. Any additional information should be added as edits to your question, with proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic. I have edited the question. Marc, sry i am not sure i follow. This works when the file is owned by the id running the script. Sub folder in zip file doesnt have its own permission does it?